# Android login with Facebook and start new activity

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

i'm doubt with how to open new activity after login success.

I did this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook

But I want an application that have a login button and after login enter in other activity,
in this tutorial after I click in login button the logout button appears
and i don't want the logout button appear.

someone can answer this?

Comment: can you look my answer below

Answer (score 1):

firstly you can call the facebooklogin activity with forresult like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,FacebookActivity_Logon.class );  
startActivityForResult(myIntent,2000);
```

and then you can call another activity in activity result like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

     if(requestCode==2000)
     {  
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(login.this,another_activity.class);         
        startActivity (myIntent);
        finish(); //if you want to do not use this
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand where i need put this part:
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,FacebookActivity_Logon.class );  
startActivityForResult(myIntent,2000);

Comment: when you start your facebook login activity

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK internally loads Login page you need to follow complete instruction

initialize

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
```

In Click Event call

```
openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
```

method is below

```
public static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity,
        boolean allowLoginUI, Session.StatusCallback statusCallback) {
        OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(activity);
        openRequest.setPermissions(CommonAppUtils.FB_BASIC_PERMISSIONS);
        openRequest.setCallback(statusCallback);

        Session session = new Session.Builder(activity).build();

        if (SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState())
                || allowLoginUI) {
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForRead(openRequest);

            return session;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Create statuscallback implementation

```
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            // you can check session state and do whatever
        }
    }
```

Be care with adding in on create

```
uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```